# How to preserve session through all tests on phpunit?

Tags: session, phpunit

I'm working on testing a shopping cart, checkout, payment process on Zend Framework with phpunit. I'm testing `ShoppingCartController` by adding products to cart, a `ShoppingCart` Model handles product additions by storing product id's in a Zend Session Namespace, and then in another test I want to test that the products were added. The same `ShoppingCart` Model retrieves a list of added products from the same Zend Session namespace variable.

The add product test looks like this and works well, and the `var_dump($_SESSION)` was added to debug and shows the products correctly:

```
public function testCanAddProductsToShoppingCart() {

    $testProducts = array(
        array(
            "product_id" => "1",
            "product_quantity" => "5"
        ),
        array(
            "product_id" => "1",
            "product_quantity" => "3"
        ),
        array(
            "product_id" => "2",
            "product_quantity" => "1"
        )
    );

    Ecommerce_Model_Shoppingcart::clean();

    foreach ($testProducts as $product) {
        $this->request->setMethod('POST')
                ->setPost(array(
                    'product_id' => $product["product_id"],
                    'quantity' => $product["product_quantity"]
                ));

        $this->dispatch($this->getRouteUrl("add_to_shopping_cart"));
        $this->assertResponseCode('200');
    }

    $products = Ecommerce_Model_Shoppingcart::getData();
    $this->assertTrue($products[2][0]["product"] instanceof Ecommerce_Model_Product);
    $this->assertEquals($products[2][0]["quantity"],
            "8");

    $this->assertTrue($products[2][1]["product"] instanceof Ecommerce_Model_Product);
    $this->assertEquals($products[2][1]["quantity"],
            "1");

    var_dump($_SESSION);
}
```

The second test attempts to retrieve the products by asking the model to do so, the `var_dump($_SESSION)` is null already at the beginning of the test. **The session variables were reset, I want to find a way to preserve them, can anyone help?**

```
public function testCanDisplayShoppingCartWidget()  {
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $this->dispatch($this->getRouteUrl("view_shopping_mini_cart"));
    $this->assertResponseCode('200');
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry for pointing you in the wrong direction. Here is [a way better way](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#fixtures.global-state) of achieving this, suggested by ashawley from #phpunit channel of irc.freenode.net:

```
<?php

# running from the cli doesn't set $_SESSION here on phpunit trunk
if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) $_SESSION = array(  );

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    protected $backupGlobalsBlacklist = array( '_SESSION' );

    public function testOne(  ) {
        $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
    }

    public function testTwo(  ) {
        $this->assertEquals( 'bar', $_SESSION['foo'] );
    }

}

?>
```

== END UPDATE

1. **In function tearDown()**: copy $_SESSION to a class attribute and
2. **In function setUp()**: copy the class attribute to $_SESSION

For example, this test fails when you remove the functions setUp() and tearDown() methods:

```
<?php
# Usage: save this to test.php and run phpunit test.php    

# running from the cli doesn't set $_SESSION here on phpunit trunk                                                                                                
if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) $_SESSION = array(  );

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public static $shared_session = array(  ); 

    public function setUp() {
        $_SESSION = FooTest::$shared_session;
    }  

    public function tearDown() {

        FooTest::$shared_session = $_SESSION;
    }  

    public function testOne(  ) {
        $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
    }  

    public function testTwo(  ) {
        $this->assertEquals( 'bar', $_SESSION['foo'] ); 
    }  
}
```

Also there is a [backupGlobals feature](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/797-Global-Variables-and-PHPUnit.html) but it doesn't work for me. You should try it thought, maybe it works on stable PHPUnit.

Comment: what would you suggest to share session beetween test cases ??

Comment: You could make a SharedSessionTestCase which extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase, and define $shared_session, setUp() and tearDown() there. Then, you could have several test case that would extend SharedSessionTestCase.

Comment: I added a much better answer.

Comment: OK thanks again , .. I'll try the new approach, and definitely will try extending PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Comment: Absolutely, that's why i left the initial post in-place which is potentially helpful... and we'll all learning so that's a win-win situation even for your clients B)

Answer (score 3):

that's a very ugly of doing that. The right way should be using dependency injection.

That implies changing your source code to use this class instead of sessions directly:

```
class Session
{
  private $adapter;
  public static function init(SessionAdapter $adapter)
  {
    self::$adapter = $adapter;
  }
  public static function get($var)
  {
      return self::$adapter->get($var);
  }
  public static function set($var, $value)
  {
    return self::$adapter->set($var, $value);
  }
}

interface SessionAdapter
{
  public function get($var);
  public function set($var, $value);
}
```

Additional information:

- http://community.sitepoint.com/t/phpunit-testing-cookies-and-sessions/36557/2
- [Using PHPUnit to test cookies and sessions, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050137/using-phpunit-to-test-cookies-and-sessions-how)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a random session id for your PHPUnit test, and then make sure you pass this session id in a cookie in every further call you make. With Curl, you would use the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option and set it to `'PHPSESSID=thesessionidofyourunittest'` as such:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=thesessionidofyourunittest');
```

I explained more in detail and with an example in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39253145/1339501).